# Has the "recommended CLRegion (CLCircularRegion) recommended monitoring radius" changed for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, gps, ios7, cllocationmanager

The description of

```
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

states the following:

> In iOS 6, regions with a radius between 1 and 400 meters work better
>   on iPhone 4S or later devices. (In iOS 5, regions with a radius
>   between 1 and 150 meters work better on iPhone 4S and later devices.)

But I cant seem to find anything that talks about iOS 7, plus the fact that iOS 7 uses CLCircularRegions instead of CLRegions.

My question is, What is the recommended radius range for devices with iOS 7?